# How to change filename on uploading on joomla custom component mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, filenames

i really need to change filename on uploading , currently my component replace files with the same name .
where should i put my code to change filename in controller or model ?

Thanks

Comment: if php code in complicated, is there any way to do this with javascript ?

Comment: You really need to add more info to this question if you want a good answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at StackExchange. You will have a better chance to get an answer if you ask your question there. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

And For uploading the file you need to write your code in the controller file and you can extend the **save()** method. check the code given below -

```
public function save($data = array(), $key = 'id')
{
    // Neccesary libraries and variables
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

    //Debugging 
    ini_set("display_error" , 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Get input object
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

    // Get posted data
    $data  = $jinput->get('jform', null, 'raw');
    $file  = $jinput->files->get('jform');

    // renaming the file 
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',JFile::makeSafe($file['pdf_file_path']['name']))));
    $filename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . $file_ext;
    // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
    if ( $filename != '' ) {

        // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
        $filepath = JPath::clean( JPATH_ROOT."/media/your_component_name/files/". $filename );

        // Move the uploaded file.
        if (JFile::upload( $file['pdf_file_path']['tmp_name'], $filepath )) {
              echo "success :)";
        } else {              
              echo "failed :(";
        }        
    }

    JRequest::setVar('jform', $data, 'post');
    $return = parent::save($data);
    return $return;
}
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: this functino works on joomla 1.5 and 2.5 but not on joomla 3, can you help me with joomla 3 too ? thanks

Comment: on joomla 3 i get this messaeg : Warning: Failed to move file!

Comment: Please check your dierectory permissions

Comment: any luck on this @ArashYazdani ?

Comment: i've checked files permissions it has full access but can't use this code to rename or move files, i'm using IIS,  I just want to rename files before they going to database not moving them , i'm stock :( please helpp

Comment: Do one thing, comment the last two lines and add this `var_dump($data)`.
then check the data array, probably one of the values are missing.

Comment: failed :(array(10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "0" ["inquiry_request_number"]=> string(1) "2" ["decription"]=> string(8) "asdfasdf" ["category"]=> string(1) "1" ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2016-03-14" ["end_time"]=> string(10) "2016-03-15" ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["contact"]=> string(8) "38262372" ["file"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["bidding"]=> string(36) "http://shazandtpp.ir/bidding" }

Comment: add `$data['file'] = $file; or $data['file'] = $file['pdf_file_path']['name']` in your code and try

Comment: can you write a code that get the filename and if file already exists rename it or add somthing to the end ?

Answer (score 0):

Which component are you using? In any case, what you will need to do is just embed the current time (just the numbers) to the filename that you upload in the component's upload script.

Comment: It's a custom component that i create it, but when i wanna upload files it will replace files with the same name ....